# I am working on a pose dataset and want to convert this data into CSV format. How to convert this data into a single row of data

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, csv

This is the data for one pose. I have a lot of data like this which i want to convert to CSV to apply machine learning algorithm. 
I am assuming I have to convert this data into a single row of comma separated values which will define a single pose.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) `numpy` for this task. Simply convert your data to a numpy array and use the function as:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [2]: x = [[[1,2], [3,4]]]                                                    

In [3]: x                                                                       
Out[3]: [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]

In [4]: np.array(x).flatten()
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

In example starting from

```
[[[1 2 3]
[5 6 7.3]
[8.2 6 3]]]
```

and run

```
<input perl -pe 's/\n//g' | sed -r 's/\]\[/,/g;s/(\[|\])//g;s/\s+/,/g'
```

you will have

```
1,2,3,5,6,7.3,8.2,6,3
```